# NullInjectorError: No provider for HttpHandler! despite HttpClient/HttpClientModule being present

Tags: angular, angular6

I'm new to an Angular-based UI project, and used vscode to generate two new components for use on the project. However, I keep getting errors whenever I push my changes to git(bitbucket) and these errors are not present when I build the project on my machine. Where do I need to provide HttpClient/HttpClientModule so that these new components can use HttpHandler?

I've added providers for HttpClientModule and HttpClient on both app.module.ts and the new components themselves.

modal-wiped-all.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgbActiveModal, NgbModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

import { OrganisationsApiService } from 'src/app/api/organisations/organisations-api.service';
import { HttpClient, HttpClientModule, HttpHandler } from '@angular/common/http';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-modal-wipedall',
  templateUrl: './modal-wiped-all.component.html',
  providers: [NgbActiveModal,
  OrganisationsApiService,
  HttpClientModule,
HttpClient,
]})
```

cleanup.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
 import { HttpClient, HttpClientModule, HttpHandler } from '@angular/common/http';
import { OrganisationsApiService } from 'src/app/api/organisations/organisations-api.service';
import { NgbModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

import { ModalWipedAllComponent } from '../modal/modal-wiped-all/modal-wiped-all.component';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-cleanup',
  templateUrl: './cleanup.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./cleanup.component.css'],
  providers: [OrganisationsApiService,
    NgbModal,
    HttpClientModule,
    HttpClient,

  ]
})


export class CleanupComponent implements OnInit {

  submitted: boolean;
  loading: boolean;
  deleted: number;

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private api: OrganisationsApiService,
    private modalService: NgbModal) {

   }
```

app.module.ts providers

```
providers: [AwsApiService,
              OrganisationsApiService,
              LabsApiService,
              UsersApiService,
              UserManagementDataService,
              ConfigDataService,
              ErrorDataService,
              DeploymentResponseDataService,
              ModalOptionsComponent,
              ModalConfigurationComponent,
              ModalUndeployLabComponent,
              ModalCreatedUserComponent,
              NgbActiveModal,
              HttpClientModule,
              HttpClient,


     { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: HttpRequestInterceptor,
      multi: true}
    ],
```

error messages:

```
CleanupComponent.CleanupComponent should createChrome 56.0.2924 (Linux 0.0.0)
<1s
Error: StaticInjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[HttpClient -> HttpHandler]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[HttpClient -> HttpHandler]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for HttpHandler!
    at NullInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NullInjector.get node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:1062:1)
    at resolveToken node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:1300:1)
    at tryResolveToken node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:1244:1)
    at StaticInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.StaticInjector.get node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:1141:1)
    at resolveToken node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:1300:1)
    at tryResolveToken node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:1244:1)
    at StaticInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.StaticInjector.get node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:1141:1)
    at resolveNgModuleDep node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:8369:1)
    at NgModuleRef_.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NgModuleRef_.get node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:9057:1)
    at resolveDep node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:9422:1)




ModalWipedAllComponent.ModalWipedAllComponent should createChrome 56.0.2924 (Linux 0.0.0)
<1s
Error: StaticInjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[HttpClient -> HttpHandler]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[HttpClient -> HttpHandler]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for HttpHandler!
    at NullInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NullInjector.get node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:1062:1)
    at resolveToken node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:1300:1)
    at tryResolveToken node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:1244:1)
    at StaticInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.StaticInjector.get node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:1141:1)
    at resolveToken node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:1300:1)
    at tryResolveToken node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:1244:1)
    at StaticInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.StaticInjector.get node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:1141:1)
    at resolveNgModuleDep node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:8369:1)
    at NgModuleRef_.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NgModuleRef_.get node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:9057:1)
    at resolveDep node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:9422:1)
```

I expect the project to build as it does locally, I instead get NullInjectorErrors

UPDATE: component.spec.ts files
ModalWipedAll

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { ModalWipedAllComponent } from './modal-wiped-all.component';

describe('ModalWipedAllComponent', () => {
  let component: ModalWipedAllComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ModalWipedAllComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ ModalWipedAllComponent ]  
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ModalWipedAllComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

CleanupComponent

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { CleanupComponent } from './cleanup.component';

describe('CleanupComponent', () => {
  let component: CleanupComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<CleanupComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ CleanupComponent ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(CleanupComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Comment: You don't have to provide HttpClient, only HttpClientModule is enough. ALso, you dont need to provide separately in each copmonent. If you have provided in root, it will be available for complete application

Comment: I have provided HttpClient Module everywhere in an attempt to fix the error. It is provided in the root module app.module.ts, and is properly imported in the same app.module.ts file. Yet the error persists.

Comment: provide the HttpClientModule before providing any service. The order matters. Best position would be to place it right after the BrowserModule in the imports array of app.module.ts

Comment: @CallumMartin check my answer.,  I have given the steps.

Comment: Noticed now.. You have placed the HttpClientModule in providers. You don't have to do that. You have to put that in the `imports` array.

Answer (score 16):

There are few steps to achieve this -

1. in your app.module.ts import `HttpClientModule` like below

   import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

and use it the `imports` array of `@NgModule` like below .

```
@NgModule({
 ...
 imports : [BrowserModule,HttpClientModule],  
 providers: [.... other services ..]
 })
```

**HttpClientModule should be added after BrowserModule. This order is important in `imports` array.**

2. Remove all the imports of `HttpClientModule` from the components . If you are importing it at the root module then it's sufficient.
3. Remove `HttpClient` from the `providers` array of `@NgModule`in the app.module.ts, it's not required . You can directly inject the instance of HttpClient in the constructor of component without adding it in providers.
4. if you are using `ng-bootstrap` then you only need to import it like below in your app.module.ts -
   `import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';`

and then use it like below

```
@NgModule({
     ...
     imports : [BrowserModule,HttpClientModule,NgbModule.forRoot()],
     providers: [.... other services ..]
     })
```

`NgbActiveModal` is not required to be added in providers.

**Update :** You also need to import the `HttpClientModule` module in your spec file for unit testing. Testbed creates a test module for testing your component. As you have injected OrganisationsApiService in the constructor of the component, you need to add it to the `providers` array of the testbed module like below .

here is the code for the spec file of `CleanupComponent` -

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { CleanupComponent } from './cleanup.component';
import { OrganisationsApiService } from 'src/app/api/organisations/organisations-api.service';

describe('CleanupComponent', () => {
  let component: CleanupComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<CleanupComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ CleanupComponent ],
      imports : [HttpClientModule],
      providers : [OrganisationsApiService ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(CleanupComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Similarly you need to do the change for the other spec file for `ModalWipedAll`

Comment: after having made some adjustments to the code, i still get this error:
Error: StaticInjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[CleanupComponent -> HttpClient]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[CleanupComponent -> HttpClient]:

The only difference here is that HttpClientModule is higher up on the list of providers and imports, as with HttpClient

Comment: What  is DynamicTestModule? is it part of your unit test file with TestBed? Can you post the code for it ?

Comment: @CallumMartin can you post the code for DynamicTestModule

Comment: I think dynamicTestModule is an inbuilt angular thing, there's no code for it in my spec.ts files. I've added those for reference, in case they are the problem. Thanks.

Comment: @CallumMartin I have updated my answer. you also need to import the module to TestBed.configureTestingModule

Comment: I have the same issue and still couldn't solve it yet

Answer (score 6):

If you are using unit testing by ng test using Jasmine and Karma, then you may need to import HttpClientTestingModule in the spec file.

Comment: If someone looking the code part of this answer here it is, in your spec.ts file import { HttpClientTestingModule } from '@angular/common/http/testing'; beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
    });
  });